# How do you derive non-relativistic momentum using energy equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, momentum, approximations

I know that $E_k=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ and $E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4$

$$p=\dfrac1c \sqrt{E^2-m^2c^4}$$

how do I derive non-relativistic momentum so that the final equation looks like

$$p=\dfrac1c\sqrt{2mE_k}$$ The units of momentum are in $\frac {\text{eV}}{c}$ and the units for mass are in $\frac{\text{eV}}{c^2}$

Comment: Your third equation is not dimensionally correct though, as the product $mE_k$ will have dimensions of $eV^2/c^2$, which will make p have dimensions $eV/c^2$.

Comment: The final equation $$p=\frac1c\times\sqrt(2mc^2E_k)$$ so the $c^2$ will cancel leaving $\frac1c\times\sqrt(eV^2)$ I don't know how it was derived though.

Comment: Your first equation is the Newtonian kinetic energy, not the relativistic kinetic energy.

Comment: A proper statement of the problem needs to distinguish symbolically (not just in the text) the relativistic momentum $p$ (in the $E^2$ equation and your first centered equation) and the non-relativistic momentum $p_{nr}$ (in your "$E_k$" equation and your second centered equation). As others have noted, your "$E_k$" is the non-relativistic kinetic energy $E_{k,nr}$ in terms of the non-relativistic momentum: $E_{k,nr}=p_{nr}^2/(2m)$, which arises in the limit of the relativistic kinetic energy $E_k$ in @Quantumness's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The $E$ given in $E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4$ is the total energy, including rest energy. The non-relativistic limit you give is specifically kinetic energy, which has the relativistic equation $E_k=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}-mc^2$

One may Taylor (or Binomial) expand the square root to give $E_k=mc^2+\dfrac{p^2c^2}{2mc^2}+\mathcal{O}(c^{-2})-mc^2$ (see how?)

The non-relativistic limit $c\to\infty$ is then manifest.

Answer (score 1):

For a free particle, the kinetic energy is the total energy minus the rest mass
$$E_{\rm k}=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}-mc^2$$
then
$$p=mc\sqrt{\left[\left(\frac{E_{\rm k}}{mc^2}\right)+1\right]^2-1}\approx \sqrt{2mE_{\rm k}}+O(c^{-1})$$
in the non-relativistic limit $E_{\rm k}\ll mc^2$.